# Instant and graceful response to the client from server side while using NServiceBus.Send

Tags: nservicebus, command-pattern

I agreed that the command pattern is an excellent way of building loosely coupled application.  My concern is how to respond to the client instantly and gracefully about the status of the request.  For example, a client making a request to place order.  In the typical way, order will be created followed by sending order id as a JSON response to browser.  In the command pattern particularly with NServiceBus, how is it possible to send the response?

Comment: What kind of response do you need to send to client? Can you respond to them like :order placed." After you send the command?

Comment: Few use cases wants to send either 'OrderId' (HTTP 201) or 'Not able to order now' (500/400) response instead of 'Order Placed' (200).  Technically, once order placement done, the invoker needs to be informed, instead of the invoker asking the status of the order placement.

Comment: without knowing your environment.
options are:
1) poll for some id (typically guid generated at the command level) to know the status of the command you sent. this can be in a database somewhere or centralised cache (eg: redis)...
2) push the result from the backend service using something like signalR..

in my case, my web application bus is a sendonly bus, which means, I cant use the "reply" feature in NSB, since my web application have no queue. I generate an ID that I return to the client once it posted the data (order) and have it poll for the result in ajax.

Comment: Thanks Sarmaad.  I am in the direction of option 2. Evaluating the SignalR option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this what Return and Reply are for?

- [Full duplex](http://docs.particular.net/samples/fullduplex/)
- [Replying to a message](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/reply-to-a-message)
- [Handling responses](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/handling-responses-on-the-client-side)